# How do I autofill a formula to skip a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, auto-form-fill

I am trying to drag data from a excel master sheet onto another excel file but the numbers are skipped per row.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E15+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E16

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E17+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E18

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E19+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E21
```

the following occurs during autofill

```
='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E15+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E16

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E16+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E17

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E17+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E18
```

I've also tried to double up the lines and have it recognize the skipping pattern but this is what I get

```
='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E15+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E16

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E17+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E18

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E17+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E18

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E19+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E21

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E19+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E21

='[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E21+'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]'!$E23
```

Comment: Which software are you doing this in? Have you tried creating the first two lines, then selecting both and dragging? This is typically how you tell Excel (if that's what you're using) about a difference in your pattern.

Comment: Yes sorry this is excel, ive edited my post for easier viewing

Comment: As you edit your question, please add the Excel tag(s), and make use of the formatting tools there in the editor to make your question as clear as it can be.

Comment: This needs `INDIRECT()` function, you could try the following: `=INDIRECT("'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E"&(ROW()*2-1)+14)+INDIRECT("'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E"&ROW()*2+14)`

Comment: BTW if you are using `MS365` could use the following as well: `=BYROW(WRAPROWS(TOCOL('[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$E,1),2),SUM)` also note the if the source file is closed then the `INDIRECT()` function will return an error `#REF!` while the one with `BYROW()` won't

Comment: Where is the sheet name?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to resolve using `INDIRECT()` function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=INDIRECT("'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E"&(ROW()*2-1)+14)+
 INDIRECT("'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E"&ROW()*2+14)
```

---

Or, bit shorter:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E"&(ROW()*2+{-1,0})+14))
```

---

**Note:** The above formula will return error --> `#REF!` if the `MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx` is not opened while working with the file where the formula is entered. It works as long as both the files are open.

Also one more drawback is the function used. `INDIRECT()` function is volatile in nature, that is it will always recalculate when ever there is a change in any open workbook, as well as it slows down the working functionality of Excel as it is single threaded. The second method using `INDIRECT()` will require to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode, based on ones version.

---

One alternative is using `TOCOL()`+`WRAPROWS()` with `BYROW()` function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     x, TOCOL('[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$E,1),
     y, ROWS(x),
     BYROW(WRAPROWS(IF(ISEVEN(y),x,VSTACK(x,0)),2),SUM))
```

---

The above formula shared works with `Office Insiders` but to make it work for `Current Channel Users` in `MS365` needs to add a `LAMBDA()`

```
=LET(
     x, TOCOL('[MASTER ITEM LIST 2024.xlsx]Sheet1'!$E:$E,1),
     y, ROWS(x),
     BYROW(WRAPROWS(IF(ISEVEN(y),x,VSTACK(x,0)),2),LAMBDA(a,SUM(a))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you, i will study this and test it out

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response, I was not in front of the computer. Yes let me know when you have time @Allen